# VB 2010 play wav files randomly Windows 8 RP

Tags: vb.net, audio, wav

I need 5 wav files to play randomly at the end of my program. I know how to get it to play one song, and I found a code on this site already but it doesn't work for me, it just plays the same song every time. Here is the code:

```
    Public Sub PlayRandomTrack()


    Dim trackNum As Integer = CInt(Rnd() * 5 + 0.5)

    Select Case trackNum
        Case 1
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CallingMonsters, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Case 2
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.McclainSisters, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Case 3
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Mendler, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Case 4
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Pray, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Case Else
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.WillowWhip, AudioPlayMode.Background)

    End Select
End Sub
```

and then I use it as:

```
    PlayRandomTrack()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> For any given initial seed, the same number sequence is generated
>   because each successive call to the Rnd function uses the previously
>   generated number as a seed for the next number in the sequence.
>
> Before calling Rnd, use the Randomize statement without an argument to
>   initialize the random-number generator with a seed based on the system
>   timer.

Comment: figured this out RIGHT after I posted this, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this instead and see if it work?

```
Dim trackNum As Integer = (New Random).Next(1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your random function:

```
    Dim tempRnd As New Random(Now.Millisecond)
    Dim trackNum As Integer = tempRnd.Next(1, 5)
```